# how to auto-delete records that have expired in data/time

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

Hey I hope you can help me,

I am trying to find a way to let rails auto-delete records who have reached their expiring date.

I got an 'appointment' model where the user can set date and time. The records are viewed ascending in a table. I want to destroy it after its done.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a common practice in databases to delete things when you do not want to see them anymore. Instead, I would suggest you to filter your table records based on the expiry date, and on the current date. This way, you are also able to display expired appointments, if necessary.

Hope this helps!